# What is the rate of amputees among-Jedi

Tags: star-wars, jedi

Based on the Star Wars movies, there seem to be quite a few Jedi who lose one or more appendage in light-saber battles. It seems like most Jedi are two-handed, but it's hard to know for sure. Is it common for a Jedi to have been injured in such a fashion, or are the Skywalkers particularly prone to premature truncation?

Comment: Since the Jedi hadn't faced a lightsaber-wielding for a thousand generations, and given the prevalence of high quality bacta, I would imagine the rate is close to 0.000001%

Comment: @Valorum Technically this is slightly different, but the numbers boil down to the same: `34 / number of Jedi`.